# Magento 2 message: "The authenticity of the gateway response could not be verified." Error Authorize.net

Tags: magento2, orders, payment, authorize.net

I am facing below error while doing payment by Authorize.net Sandbox Account

> "The authenticity of the gateway response could not be verified."

I tried to resolve this by creating new Transaction Key and Signature Key but nothing happened.

While Checkout Order is not placed and gives above error but in Authorize.net they show Unsettled Transaction, check below:
[image: ne]

**Payment log gives success message**

```
    [2019-07-08 10:03:59] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'payload_type' => 'createTransactionRequest',
    'merchantAuthentication' => 
    array (
      'name' => '8s92nHBP64',
      'transactionKey' => '438Fea4rnT835S33',
    ),
    'transactionRequest' => 
    array (
      'transactionType' => 'authOnlyTransaction',
      'amount' => '500.50',
      'payment' => 
      array (
        'opaqueData' => 
        array (
          'dataDescriptor' => 'COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT',
          'dataValue' => 'eyJjb2RlIjoiNTBfMl8wNjAwMDUyRTg2NjI4RTM1REJERTlBRkVGRTA2MjY4MTg3RkQ1RkRFMUE0NzRCODBCMTk3N0MwOTIyM0E1NTExN0NFNTdDRTY2NDgyNUQ4RjAyQ0VFQjJBM0MwMEUwMTdFMTkyRTZFIiwidG9rZW4iOiI5NTYyNTgwMjM1NjM1OTM3NDAzNTAxIiwidiI6IjEuMSJ9',
        ),
      ),
      'solution' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'AAA102993',
      ),
      'order' => 
      array (
        'invoiceNumber' => '000000017',
      ),
      'poNumber' => NULL,
      'customer' => 
      array (
        'id' => NULL,
        'email' => 'himani.magneto@gmail.com',
      ),
      'billTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'bewdfjb',
        'lastName' => 'bb',
        'company' => 'nbn',
        'address' => '86 Jones Common, Greenview, FK8 1LD',
        'city' => 'Indianapolis',
        'state' => 'Greenview',
        'zip' => 'FK8 1LD',
        'country' => 'GB',
      ),
      'shipTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'bewdfjb',
        'lastName' => 'bb',
        'company' => 'nbn',
        'address' => '86 Jones Common, Greenview, FK8 1LD',
        'city' => 'Indianapolis',
        'state' => 'Greenview',
        'zip' => 'FK8 1LD',
        'country' => 'GB',
      ),
      'customerIP' => '27.109.19.234',
      'userFields' => 
      array (
        'userField' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'transactionType',
            'value' => 'authOnlyTransaction',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'response' => '{"transactionResponse":{"responseCode":"1","authCode":"R8Y1BD","avsResultCode":"Y","cvvResultCode":"P","cavvResultCode":"2","transId":"40034332102","refTransID":"","transHash":"","testRequest":"0","accountNumber":"XXXX4444","accountType":"MasterCard","messages":[{"code":"1","description":"This transaction has been approved."}],"userFields":[{"name":"transactionType","value":"authOnlyTransaction"}],"transHashSha2":"80F1E27E02A4F3AD91851A4828EDE9CDF6728A5493556AE3228A8D57245D85693D987738705E273E883A2C2A80ED73230CE4B7C399006BC3929239AD845DC65B","SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0},"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}',
) [] []
```

Please help me!

Comment: Did you apply Authorize.Net Direct Post from MD5 to SHA-512 patches?

Comment: I am using Magento2.3.2 in which magento already applied this patch, @MSA

Comment: have you tried with proper first name and last name in checkout that might be the possible issue

Comment: @nikunj yes I tried but nothing changed,

Comment: you need to check if any third-party extension or customization affecting checkout process

Comment: To test this, I installed a new Magento 2.3.2 without any extension and module and it is not working. @nikunj

Comment: then it might be the issue with your sandbox account

Comment: @nikunj, In my Sandbox Account, I had created new Transaction Key and Signature Key and I am using them, then What more will left in Sandbox Account to fixed?

Comment: have you tried with real account details?

Comment: In real Account, It was not working with test card details and I have not tested with Real time payment. @nikunj

Comment: sometimes you cant checkout with sandbox account and it will work with a real account

Comment: @nikunj I tried with real Payement in production mode and it worked..

Comment: @nikunj Thankyou :) Happy Coding..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I figured it out, everything configured correctly and Payment Gateway is also working, The only thing is it didn't worked in sandbox mode and when I switched to production mode, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a Magento/Authorize using the wrong key to encode/decode the hash, so regenerating a new key and but make sure to check "Disable Old Transaction Key Immediately" and "Disable Old Signature Key Immediately" while generating the new keys in Authorize.net admin

```
    if (!$valid && $amount > 0) {
        $hash = $this->{$generateFunction}(
            $storedHash,
            $this->config->getLoginId($storeId),
            '0.00',
            $transactionResponse['transId'] ?? ''
        );
        $valid = Security::compareStrings($hash, $transactionResponse[$hashField]);
    }

    ....

    return $this->createResult(
        false,
        [
            __('The authenticity of the gateway response could not be verified.')
        ],
        [self::ERROR_TRANSACTION_HASH]
    );
```

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490220/magento-2-3-1-authorize-net-payment-method-the-authenticity-of-the-gateway-res